# Why is my UICollectionView not showing at all?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

I am using storyboards, and my UICollectionView with a basic custom cell is not showing at all? My simulator is constantly running a version of my storyboard when my "Next" button was at the middle of the screen, obviously now it is at the bottom as shown here along with all the identities and links created in the storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohjtQ.jpg

```
import UIKit

class CategoryViewController: UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var categoryCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self

    NetworkingClient.fetchRecipeCategories{ (recipeCategories) in
        //print(recipeCategories)
    }
    categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
 }
}

extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print("Taptaptap")
  }

}

extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
    
    if let testCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "categoryCell", for: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell{
        testCell.configure(with: indexPath.row)
        cell = testCell
        print("test1")
    }
    print("test2")

    return cell
   }
}
 /*
  extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 }
 */
```

And my my custom view cell :

```
class CategoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
static let identifier: String = "CategoryCollectionViewCell"

@IBOutlet weak var categoryImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet private weak var testLabel: UILabel!

func configure(with id: Int){
    testLabel.text = String(id)
    
    categoryImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    categoryImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
}
```

Sorry for the formatting...

Comment: Have you set appropriate constraints on your collection view?  Use the "debug view hierarchy in Xcode to confirm the location and size of your collection view.

Answer (score 0):

Register your custom collectionview cell named "categoryCell" in viewDidLoad()

```
    categoryCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "categoryCell", bundle: 
    nil),forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "categoryCell")
    categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
    categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
```